# create a three dimension matrix from a numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, optimization, vector

the title essentialy, i have this array

```
       i   j  d  Uijd
0      1   1  0     1
1      1   1  1     1
2      1   1  2     2
3      1   1  3     1
4      1   1  4     1
...   ..  .. ..   ...
1570  15  15  2     1
1571  15  15  3     1
1572  15  15  4     1
1573  15  15  5     0
1574  15  15  6     2
```

i and j are origin and destiny respectively, and d is the day, i want to make a three dimension matrix and call it like U[i,j,d], but i don't know how. I tried using pandas but i didnt know how to use it

Im pretty new to python so im clueless

thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you can use `.reshape` on a numpy array to convert the dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) DataFrame as input, sorted and non missing indices, you should be able to [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
U = df['Uijd'].to_numpy().reshape(15, 15, 7)
```

For a more generic method, you can extract the shape from the DataFrame using [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
U = df['Uijd'].to_numpy().reshape(df[['i', 'j', 'd']].nunique())
```

##### Alternative

If you really want to be able to run `U[i, j, d]`, or to handle missing combinations, an alternative could be to set up an empty array and to assign the values:

```
U = np.zeros(df[['i', 'j', 'd']].max()+1, dtype=df['Uijd'].dtype)

U[tuple(zip(*df[['i', 'j', 'd']].values))] = df['Uijd']

U.shape
# (16, 16, 7)

U[15, 15, 6]
# 2
```